# There exists a real number so that $X_n$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, conditional-expectation

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $Y_n$ be a sequence for which there exists constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with 
>   $$
> E(Y_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=\alpha Y_n +\beta Y_{n-1}
> $$
>   for each $n$. Show that there exists a real number $a$ such that $X_n=aY_n+Y_{n-1}$ is a martingale.

Here the problem doesn't state it, but I am assuming that $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a filtration and $Y_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$.

This is my work so far. If I want $X_n$ to be a martingale then I need $E(X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=X_n$. So we need $E(aY_{n+1}+Y_n\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=aY_n+Y_{n-1}$, but 
$$
E(aY_{n+1}+Y_n\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=aE(Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n)+Y_n=(a\alpha+1) Y_n + a\beta Y_{n-1}
$$

So in order for $X_n$ to be a martingale we would need the constant $a$ to satisfy, $a=1/\beta,$ and $a=1/(1-\alpha).$

This is where I see an issue, unless $\alpha+\beta=1$ I don't see how such an $a$ can exist.

Is there something I am missing here?

For reference this problem is problem 9.12 from Probability, by Karr.

Comment: Your calculations are correct and you didn't miss anything. We really have to *assume* that $\alpha+\beta=1$; otherwise the claim does, in general, not hold true.

Comment: The statement $Y_n\in\mathcal F_n$ should be "$Y_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable" or $\sigma(Y_n)\subset\mathcal F_n$.

Comment: $Y_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$ is a common shorthand for $Y_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable.